# uuid/rider_id and user_id from two end points is the same?

Tags: uber-api

So is the `user_id` from POST webhook url `all_trips.status_changed`:

```
{
    "event_id": "3a3f3da4-14ac-4056-bbf2-d0b9cdcb0777",
    "event_time": 1427343990,
    "event_type": "all_trips.status_changed",
    "meta": {
        "user_id": "d13dff8b",
        "resource_id": "2a2f3da4",
        "status": "accepted"
    },
    "resource_href": "https://api.uber.com/v1.2/requests/2a2f3da4"
}
```

the same as `rider_id` from GET `requests` or GET `me` `rider_id` or the GET `me` `uuid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User_ID is the same as UUID, but Rider ID is not the same.